# How to transfer external pages in Web View (Android Studio) to Chrome

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, webview

I wrote a simple program and used webview.
My problem is that links to pages that do not follow the https://irunisenter.com rule also open in the program. It's like turning my Google Play into Facebook by clicking on a link!
Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mywebView.loadUrl("https://irunisenter.com/");
        WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }
    public class mywebClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    />
```

Does anyone have a solution for redirecting external links to an external browser?

Answer (score 0):

option 1 : Use CustomTabsIntent to call chrome inside your webview.

option 2 : Use intent method to go to browser directly for certain urls. use the below method

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(s));
startActivity(i);
```